# How to update Google Chrome past v70

Tags: google-chrome

I recently had this problem upgrading Google Chrome in 18.04. I noticed my version had was stuck at 70.x, even though the most stable version was 77.x. I tried re-adding the PPA a bunch of times, but that just caused more errors, because it was now "configured multiple times." This obscured the one crucial error I missed, whenever I ran `sudo apt-get update`:

```
E: Repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Google, Inc.' to 'Google LLC'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

Comment: oh yes, you are correct. I searched but did not find that question.

Answer (score 2):

As you determined, `sudo apt update` will offer to fix this for you.

With `apt-get`, you need to specify the corresponding option:

```
sudo apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:

https://medium.com/@andrea_45267/how-to-solve-the-changed-its-origin-value-from-google-inc-to-google-llc-apt-error-4675f891be1f

TL;DR:

Run:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then enter `y` when prompted:

```
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N]
```

I guess `apt-get` doesn't give you this prompt; only `apt` does? Anyway, such a simple fix, but the solution had been eluding me for weeks. Hope this answer saves someone else the same grief.

Comment: apt is for users (it's use different interactive things). apt-get is for different programs and scripts (stable output for parsing).